# How to specify an absolute URL for generated chunk files in angular (CLI 7)

Tags: angular, angular-cli-v7

I'm having issues as I serve my javascript files from a CDN. IN new angular cli (v7) when I enable lazy loading the generated chunk files are loaded from the root directory by default, however I want them to be served from a different url (s3 in this case).

How it is being loaded:

```
...
http://<website_url>/polyfills.js
http://<website_url>/runtime.js
http://<website_url>/main.js
...
```

How I want it to load:

```
...
http://<website_url>/abolutepath/polyfills.js
http://<website_url>/abolutepath/runtime.js
http://<website_url>/abolutepath/main.js
...
```

Just to mention I have tried base href and it doesn't work. It still loads the chunk fiels from root.

```
<base href="/abolutepath/">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify `--deployUrl` when using build

```
ng build --prod --deployUrl http://<website_url>/abolutepath
```

Basically this is when you upload files into custom folder + if want to use CDN

Comment: Thanks, that solves it. I read somewhere that angular CLI 7 doesn't support deployUrl params (obviously incorrect)

Comment: Yep, my bad, was in a hurry so.